# Command raised an exception: TypeError: Misc.search() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'message'

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been making this google search function for my discord bot and i keep getting the error shown above. I've tried many things but cant seem to work it out. Heres my code:

```
@commands.command()
async def search(self, ctx, *, arg, message):
    gsearch = ctx.message.content
    URL = f'https://serpapi.com/search.json?q={gsearch}&tbm=isch&ijn=0&api_key={token}'
    if ctx.message.content in blacklistsearch:
        await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(URL)
```

Comment: However you are calling the `search` function (which we cannot see in the code you posted), you are not passing the message as an argument, which is required for `ctx.message.content`

Comment: Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. "I can't seem to work it out" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message (copy and paste, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and format as code) and explain the "many things" that you tried, along with your existing understanding of the problem. But as a hint: where the code says `search(self, ctx, *, arg, message):`, what is the purpose of the `, message` part? Where do you expect that value to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two arguments after `*`, you can only have one. Based on your code, you won't need the 'message' argument anyway, only 'arg'. There are other problems you will run into too, such as the fact that you are taking in the whole message as an argument, rather than what you've written after `!search`. Do view the revised code below, as well as an example image.

```py
@commands.command()
async def search(self, ctx, *, arg):
    gsearch = arg.lower()
    # so if you write "!search EXAMPLE test"
    # -> gsearch = "example test"
    URL = f'https://serpapi.com/search.json?q={gsearch}&tbm=isch&ijn=0&api_key={token}'
    if any(word in gsearch for word in blacklistsearch):
        # if any of the words in blacklistsearch is in gsearch
        await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(URL)
```

[image: Example of working]

Please note that for the sake of testing, `gsearch` was sent instead of `URL` in the above image.